# net.ipv4.ip_forward lxc vm ping DUP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, ping, lxc

I run LXC Linux containers and so I have `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` set on the host so that I can ping internet (google.com) from inside the LXC container.

However, when I run VirtualBox VMs in the same environment and bridge to the wlan wireless interface I get duplicate ICMP packets (DUP!).  I can stop the duplicate packets in the VirtualBox VM by setting `net.ipv4.ip_forward=0` on the host, but then this breaks the resolution of internet in the LXC containers.

How can I prevent the DUP! pings in the VM and leave `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` set?  Thanks.

Comment: Your question doesn't have much to do with programming. Have you tried _[ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)_?

Comment: Thank you for your reply I will try ServerFault.